# What is the difference between 北 and 北部

Tags: meaning, kanji, kanji-choice

What is the main difference between 北 and 北部?
I heard that's words that contain 2 kanji sounds more polite, but not sure that it's the current situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

北 is the cardinal direction "north".
北部 is a combination of 北(north) and 部(part), and refers to the northern region/section/area of a landmass.